# Converting file with XML tags & csv's into a proper XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a following text file

```
<IPG>298,"2013-06-25 16:00","Modication"
 <IIP>
 13925,2,"ippico",2,2,"SGT","S.G.TEATINO TR/PM",2,8,0,"BELLO","BUONO"
 <CR>
  13925,10,"SGT",2,"SGT  CORSA 2",2,9,9,5571141,0,1,"2013-06-25 16:00",10,13925010
   <CV>
    13925010,1,"HOLZ","A","A.STO","",1,20,1600,0,0,0,3,14,3,14,0,0
    13925011,2,"BREED AND","A","G.PACI","",1,20,550,0,0,0,3,14,3,14,0,0
   </CV>
  </CR>
 </IIP>
  <GE>A,100,331,332,353,354,372,373
  </GE>
<IPG>
```

I want to convert above file into proper XML structure treating each comma-separated values ( as you can see csv's inside the tag)  as an XML node or attribute in its own right.

For example,
`<IPG>` tag should be

```
<IPG id="298" date="2013-06-25 16:00" desc="Medication">
```

For `<CV>` tag each line under tags should be a individual node like

```
<CV id="13925010" Status="1" ......../>
<CV id="13925011" Status="2"........./>
```

Any idea how can I achieve this using c# 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, since it's an entirely custom format you'd likely have to read in the file line by line, do some string parsing and manipulation to convert it into a usable in-memory object, then output that object however you like (XML serialization, in this case).  Have you made any attempt to this yet?

Comment: Hi David, I'm not able to manipulate it. can you show me any example?

Comment: There are a lot of functions on the `String` object, for starters.  Substring, IndexOf, etc.  What are you trying and where, specifically, are you stuck?  Are you stuck on trying to load the file?  Parse a specific value from it?  So far this question is very broad, but if you specify what you've tried and where you're having problems we might be able to help.

Answer (score -3):

You can't use split(",") ?

If you can use it, you must take it in table and after you can read it with for().